# After factory resetting and rebooting my modem, I still can't log in to my modem with the default username and password

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

For countless hours I've been trying to figure out the solution for a problem I've been having. I clicked on an option for my Remote Access panel in my Router (My router model is Sagemcom F@st5260 Router), and then the page got all messed up so I logged out and I can't log back in. I've factory reset it and rebooted it and every time it just says the username and password are incorrect. Any help?

Comment: How are you connecting? Some routers don't allow admin over WiFI, only ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

looking here: http://support.routercheck.com/Sagemcom/F%40ST+5260/DefaultPassword-0.html seems like the defaults could be admin/admin which you've probably tried or possibly blank/blank. In general would try every combo of /admin/root for user/pass.

If the firmware was updated/changed the default user/pass could be specific to that firmware revision, you could look around for release notes for the specific version (most resets don't fall back to an older factory firmware, just reset settings for the current version).

Other things worth trying are how you're connected to the device, ideally via ethernet & not over wifi.

Good luck :-)